# insertionSort: order numbers over 2^32

Tags: c, long-integer, insertion-sort

I'm implementing the InsertionSort Algorithm, but I have to run it on a specific dataset of numbers larger than 2^32. For simplicity, I've created a little array of example to test the program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void insertionSort(unsigned long long a[]) {
    int i, j;
    int key;

    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        key = a[i];
        j = i-1;

        while(j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j+1] = a[j]; 
            j = j-1; 
        }
        a[j+1] = key;
    }
}

int main() {
    // example array
    unsigned long long c [] = {40000000000LL, 10000000000LL, 20000000000LL, 30000000000LL};

    printf("Before insertionSort: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { printf("%llu,\n", c[i]); }

    printf("\n");

    insertionSort(c);

    printf("After insertionSort: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { printf("%llu,\n", c[i]); }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and the output on my terminal looks like this:

```
Before insertionSort:
40000000000,
10000000000,
20000000000,
30000000000,

After insertionSort:
1410065408,
40000000000,
18446744072234715136,
18446744073644780544,
```

And it's a weird output! Does someone know where is my mistake? I just want to print the array it in the right way!

Comment: Try compiling with warnings enabled.

Comment: Temporary variable `key` is an `int` not an `unsigned long long`

Comment: @Mysticial Already tried it out... it gives me 0 warnings and 0 errors... I used “gcc - o insertionSort insertionSort.c”

Comment: @deamentiaemundi you’re right! I didn’t notice!

Comment: Now try adding `-Wall -Wextra -WPedantic`

Comment: Let's try: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tDk1V5dVjQmDWc2d , https://wandbox.org/permlink/iz3AZCXoXTyjx8Ed

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I tried it out and it worked! It was the key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `key`value must be `unsigned long long`to work.